# autoscaling php-fpm in AWS ECS

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, autoscaling, amazon-ecs

I have a t3.medium instance managed by ASG and used by ECS. My application requires approximately 25% of the capacity of this instance to operate at a minimum. will work in the standard nginx + php_fpm dockerized configuration. With that, I thought of 2 strategies for the automatic scaling of ECS tasks and I couldn't judge which one is the best due to the lack of knowledge with php.

1 - Configure 4 tasks per instance (25% each, 100% of the instance) and have granularity (and multiprocessing?)

2 - Configure only 1 task with 100% of the instance's capacity

Reading about php-fpm, it is not multithreaded, but it is multiprocess... I don't know how to decide about the best...

Before all, thanks!

Comment: How about two t3.small instances in different AZs with one container per server. That way you get redundancy and higher availability.

Comment: With PHP I'd be more worried about the Memory used than the CPU, especially on a T family instance since they have fairly low memory per instance relative to the CPU speed (as long as its not out of CPU credits, but T3's have Unlimited mode enabled by default, so that shouldn't be an issue)

Comment: I don't know how php deep work, but cpu is always the problem during tests... Anyway, the core of the problem is about php-fpm, many tasks for one instance, or one task with all instance capacity and how it works in deep... Thanks!